# Временная сложность алгоритма в среднем на примере HashMap.get

Tags: java, алгоритм, java-hashmap

В **лучшем случае**, элемент из `HashMap` можно получить за константное время `O(1)`.

В **худшем случае**, при условии, что корзина организована в виде связного списка, элемент из `HashMap` можно получить за линейное время `O(n)`.

А какая будет сложность получения элемента из `HashMap` **в среднем**? И как определить эту оценку?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/619929/10353

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для хеширования `O(1)` - в среднем. Расчеты и доказательства имеются, например, в "Искусстве программирования" Кнута или "Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ" Кормена с соавторами.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, а какая сложность в среднем, например, доступа к элементу связного списка? `HashMap` взят просто для примера, хотелось бы узнать метод оценки сложности в среднем хотя бы для какой-нибудь простой структуры данных.

Comment: @Burence `O(N)` очевидно. Потому что, `O(N/2)==O(N)` =)

Comment: @Burence в зависимости от кол-ва элементов в корзине(Node), используются разные реализации. При большом кол-ве элементов используется реализация TreeNode, у которой худший случай - log(n)